# Writing a new column in csv file based on if condition

Tags: python, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I want to add a new column which adds two existing columns on basis of if condition that tweet is a Retweet or not.
I have following csv output from my python code : [csv image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaBmt.png)

Now, i want to implement condition that if tweet is a retweet, ie;

```
   file1 = open(string.csv, 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(file1)
for r in rows :
   if Tweet[r]!="RT @***" :
        new_col=[col[3],col[4]]
        newcol.append(new_col)
    else :
        new_col=0       
file1.close()   


file2 = open(file.csv, 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(file2)
writer.writerows(newcol)
file2.close()
```

I'm having trouble implementing it. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change this syntax file2 = open(file.csv, 'wb')
To file2 = open(file.csv, 'a')

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `startswith()` method which checks whether a string starts with a substring.

```
import csv
with open('tweets.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        if row[0].startswith("RT @"):
            // It's a retweet
        else:
            // It's not a retweet
```